# Points determining pairwise intersecting circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Consider a set of $n$ pairwise intersecting circles in a plane. It is obviously not the case that there exists a single point which constitutes their intersection. One can however choose $k$ points in the plane such that every circle contains at least one of the $k$ points. This is in a sense analogous to there being a "$1$-intersection point". Thus, generalizing to $k$-intersection points, what is the smallest $k$ for a given $n$. In other words, how many points determine $n$ pairwise intersecting circles in this way?

Perhaps an incidence structure between circles and points, or its graph could be used to enumerate? I am not entirely sure. Thank you for input.

Comment: If you consider tangent circles intersecting in one point, then the minimum $k$ is $1$, otherwise $2$.

Comment: Are your circles with the same radius, and/or can we assume that it is so ?

Comment: Are the issues treated [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.03158.pdf) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/263113/88984) the same as your own issue which is, honestly, not very clear to me.

Comment: @JeanMarie The first paper on disk stabbing is the thing I've been looking for, thank you! Could you point me to something that also discusses the limits on $n$ for a stabbing number of $2$? The paper uses the Hally-triple lemma for the bound on less than $8$ disks, but I figure there should be stronger bounds on $n\le5$ or even $n\le6$.

Answer (score 2):

The circles on the left had one intersecting point (they are all tangent to the same point, and all centers are on the same axis). If you don't like single point, you can get two intersection points, like for the circle on the right. All centers are on the same axis, and all circles go through the two intersection points.

[image]